# Specification language for specifying both Objects and Primitive data types

Tags: formal-modeling, formal-methods, object-oriented

I am looking for an specification language, which supports both primitive data types and objects. I already know about [Object-Z](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.128.2294&rep=rep1&type=pdf). But I am wondering if there is any other Specification language that I can use.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the specification language? There are many ways to formalize and analyse *specific* OO languages, see e.g. [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Modeling_Language).

Comment: I am not interested to be focused in any language. Instead, interested to study the formalities behinds Objects and Classes in general. JML that you mentioned ( I think there was a typo on your post) is not discussing the semantics behind classes and objects; it is Hoare style specification of Java programs!

Comment: So it sounds like you want an *abstract calculus* of objects rather than a *specification language*.